# How to add indentation to the yaml file with yaml dump

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does anyone know how to add indentation to the yaml file with yaml dump

Current when I did yaml.dump, it shows below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gz59.png)

```
data = {
    "get_response": [
        {
            "field1": "string1",
            "field2": "string2",
            "field3": "string3",
            "field4": "string4",
        }
    ]
}
with open(
    "testdata/path/example.yaml", "w"
) as outfile:
    yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to load the yaml file and for that I suggest [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)

`pip install pyyaml`

---

```
import uuid
import yaml

with open("sample.yaml", 'r') as infile:
    data = yaml.load(infile)

data["variable_a"] = str(uuid.uuid1())

with open("sample.yaml", 'w') as outfile:
    data = yaml.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: Hi Jab, I have installed the pyyaml and pasted your code into my IDE, and I got following error program.py:None (program.py)
program.py:7: in <module>
    data["variable_a"] = str(uuid.uuid1())
E   TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: That's dependent on how the YAML file is set up I believe. I'm not very familiar with YAML, this was just an example to get you started, but if you include the data in it's entirety in the question I can see what's causing the issue